# How to remove the object tag from my HTML using Java

Tags: java, regex, string

Hi I am trying to remove the object tag from my HTML content using Java so that I can render the HTML in devices which do not support Flash

```
<object classid="clsid:F08DF954-8592-11D1-B16A-00C0F0283628" id="Slider1" width="100" height="50">
  <param name="BorderStyle" value="1" />
  <param name="MousePointer" value="0" />
  <param name="Enabled" value="1" />
  <param name="Min" value="0" />
  <param name="Max" value="10" />
</object>
```

Comment: Why are you trying to remove it? And did you consider trying not to put it in there in the first place (e.g. server-side)?

Comment: actually this content is persisted in the db so i have to remove the content inside and including <object> tag so that i can use it to serve on mobile/iphone

Comment: In principle, every HTML user agent should ignore `<object>` elements it can't handle (and instead interpret their contents), so the removing should not be necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This regex must do the trick:

```
<\/?object(\s\w+(\=\".*\")?)*\>
```

Comment: this regex is not compiling as a java string

Comment: @Dhirenda: Does not have to, to be a regex :-) You need to double and backslashes to include it as a string literal (apart from those before the `"`).

Answer (score 0):

You could just use Tagsoup (http://ccil.org/~cowan/XML/tagsoup/), which is an xml parser which can read from html, even if badly formatted (doesn't need to be xhtml or even conform).

You then can just remove all object tags using xpath.

This is much safer than a regex, which is difficult to maintain if you want to master all edge cases.

Answer (score 0):

The `OBJECT` HTML element may be nested. Since Java does not provide a native regex recursive expression, you cannot directly match an outermost `OBJECT` element with a single regex. You *can*, however, craft a regex to match an *innermost* `OBJECT` element, and iterate, replacing them from the "inside-out" until there are none left. Here is a tested Java snippet which does precisely that:

```java
String regex = "<object\\b[^>]*>[^<]*(?:(?!</?object\\b)<[^<]*)*</object\\s*>";
String resultString = null;
java.util.regex.Pattern p = java.util.regex.Pattern.compile(
            regex,
            java.util.regex.Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE |
            java.util.regex.Pattern.UNICODE_CASE);
java.util.regex.Matcher m = p.matcher(subjectString);
while (m.find())
{ // Iterate until there are no OBJECT elements.
    resultString = m.replaceAll("");
    m = p.matcher(resultString);
}
System.out.println(resultString);
```

**CAVEATS:** As many will undoubtedly point out: ***"You can't parse HTML with regex!"*** And they are correct (if your solution must work reliably 100% of the time). Although the solution above will work for a lot of cases, be aware that it has some limitations and there are certain things which can trip it up, namely:

1. An `"<OBJECT...>"` start or `"</OBJECT>"` end tag may not appear in any `CDATA` strings such as in SCRIPT or STYLE tags, or within any tag attribute, or within any HTML comment. e.g. `<p title="evil <OBJECT> attribute">` or `<SCRIPT>alert("Bad <OBJECT> script here!");</SCRIPT>`, or `<!-- <OBJECT> inside a comment -->`.
2. The `<OBJECT>` start tag may not contain any angle brackets in its attributes.

These special cases should be pretty rare and the code above should work just fine for most (if not all) HTML files you have lying around.